# How can i adjust the span height of neighboring spans according to highest span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can i adjust every violet colored span to the ones i the same row so that whenever there is more containt in one `<span>`, those on the same row strech vertically also.

height = auto does work but it does not solve the issue of the span in same rows.

I went for the `<span>`, maybe i should've build it with `<td>` and `<tr>`

Here is the code snippet with HTML CSS and JS

```js
const weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednasday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

let planningsection = document.createElement("div");
planningsection.className = "planning";

let days = document.createElement("div");
days.className = "jours";

planningsection.appendChild(days);
$("#plannings_one")[0].appendChild(planningsection);

weekdays.map(e => {
  // Création d'un span
  let day = document.createElement("span");
  day.className = "jour_one";
  let dayText = document.createTextNode(e);

  // On insere dans chaque span un jour et le span dans la div jours
  day.appendChild(dayText);
  days.appendChild(day);
})

let section = document.createElement("section");
section.className = "callender_one";

planningsection.appendChild(section);

for (planning = 0; planning < 7; planning++) {

  let colonne = document.createElement("div");
  colonne.className = "horaire_one";
  colonne.id = ("col" + planning);

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "dispo_one_rpv";
    // On rajoute un identifiant à la case en fonction de la colonne
    span.id = (colonne.id + i);
    // let plageText = document.createTextNode("Dispo / id: " + span.id);
    let plageText = document.createTextNode("");
    span.appendChild(plageText);
    colonne.appendChild(span);

    section.appendChild(colonne);
  }
}
let box = $("#col110")[0];
newText = document.createTextNode("Hello This is a text to show what it is happening right now");
box.appendChild(newText);
```

```css
#main-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.plage_rpv {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
}

.horaire {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
}

#plannings_one {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
}

.dispo_one_rpv {
  /* line-height: 2.9; */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bb12e8;
  text-align: center;
}

.callender_one {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.horaire_one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 14.32%;
}

.jours {
  display: flex;
}

.jour_one {
  width: 14.32%;
  line-height: 2.5;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="planning-main_rpv">
    <section id="main-section">
      <div id="horaire">
        <div class="horaire">Horaires</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">08:00 - 08:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">08:30 - 09:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">09:00 - 09:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">09:30 - 10:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">10:00 - 10:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">10:30 - 11:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">11:00 - 11:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">11:30 - 12:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">12:00 - 12:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">12:30 - 13:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">13:00 - 13:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">13:30 - 14:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">14:00 - 14:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">14:30 - 15:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">15:00 - 15:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">15:30 - 16:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">16:00 - 16:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">16:30 - 17:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">17:00 - 17:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">17:30 - 18:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">18:00 - 18:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">18:30 - 19:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">19:00 - 19:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">19:30 - 20:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">20:00 - 20:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">20:30 - 21:00</div>
      </div>
      <div id=plannings_one>

      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the layout is defined by column rather than by row.  If it was done by row, you could use min-height.  Alternatively, consider using an html grid [Using a grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) as this might give you better control.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation :**

For **CSS**, just replace `height` property with `min-height` for the same value in `.dispo_one_rpv`.

---

For **JavaScript**, notice that I have added two functions `calc_max()` and `set_heights()`. Whenever you append textNode inside the `box` element, update the `ind` variable like :

```js
ind = $(box).index() + 1;
```

and call function `calc_max()`. It will automatically calculate the element with maximum height, and set the height of all the elements in the entire row to the calculated value.

```js
const weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednasday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

let planningsection = document.createElement("div");
planningsection.className = "planning";

let days = document.createElement("div");
days.className = "jours";

planningsection.appendChild(days);
$("#plannings_one")[0].appendChild(planningsection);

weekdays.map(e => {
  let day = document.createElement("span");
  day.className = "jour_one";
  let dayText = document.createTextNode(e);

  day.appendChild(dayText);
  days.appendChild(day);
})

let section = document.createElement("section");
section.className = "callender_one";

planningsection.appendChild(section);

for (planning = 0; planning < 7; planning++) {

  let colonne = document.createElement("div");
  colonne.className = "horaire_one";
  colonne.id = ("col" + planning);

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "dispo_one_rpv";
    span.id = (colonne.id + i);
    let plageText = document.createTextNode("");
    span.appendChild(plageText);
    colonne.appendChild(span);

    section.appendChild(colonne);
  }
}
let box = $("#col110")[0];
newText = document.createTextNode("Hello This is a text to show what it is happening right now");
box.appendChild(newText);

var ind = $(box).index() + 1;

function calc_max() {
  let max_height = $('#horaire div:eq(' + ind + ')').height();
  $('.horaire_one span:nth-child(' + ind + ')').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > max_height) {
      max_height = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  
  set_heights(max_height);
}

calc_max();

function set_heights(height){
  $('#horaire div:eq(' + ind + ')').height(height);
  $('.horaire_one span:nth-child(' + ind + ')').height(height);
}
```

```css
#main-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.plage_rpv {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
}

.horaire {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
}

#plannings_one {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
}

.dispo_one_rpv {
  /* line-height: 2.9; */
  min-height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #bb12e8;
  text-align: center;
}

.callender_one {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.horaire_one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 14.32%;
}

.jours {
  display: flex;
}

.jour_one {
  width: 14.32%;
  line-height: 2.5;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="planning-main_rpv">
    <section id="main-section">
      <div id="horaire">
        <div class="horaire">Horaires</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">08:00 - 08:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">08:30 - 09:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">09:00 - 09:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">09:30 - 10:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">10:00 - 10:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">10:30 - 11:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">11:00 - 11:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">11:30 - 12:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">12:00 - 12:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">12:30 - 13:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">13:00 - 13:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">13:30 - 14:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">14:00 - 14:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">14:30 - 15:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">15:00 - 15:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">15:30 - 16:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">16:00 - 16:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">16:30 - 17:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">17:00 - 17:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">17:30 - 18:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">18:00 - 18:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">18:30 - 19:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">19:00 - 19:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">19:30 - 20:00</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">20:00 - 20:30</div>
        <div class="plage_rpv">20:30 - 21:00</div>
      </div>
      <div id=plannings_one>

      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok so if i'm correct, this is actually working for my box variable only right now. Maybe i should loop this and create a ```box_ind``` that will be equal to each ```id``` in order to check if anything is inside and if its the case, i call those functions

Comment: @Bob, Right now it's working for a particular `span`, and is just for demonstration. You're supposed to update the `ind` variable and then call `calc_max()`, every time you append any text node in a span (I have assumed that you will initialize `box` for the span, each time).

Comment: Can you explain what do you do in `calc_max` ? I assume that `max_height` saves the heights of all `#horaire` and you compare heights of each `span` with `#horaire` height so you can adjust the height ?

Comment: No, it's not like that. `calc_max` is the function that you invoke. The `ind` has the index of the updated element. It then iterates through all the elements, with same index, and check if there is any other element, with greater height. If there is one, `max_height` is set to the height of that element. After that, `set_max` is called, which assigns new height to the elements.

Comment: Alright, but how can i automatize this to each cell, so i dont have to manually enter `box` value?

Comment: The part where you would be appending textNode in your code, you've to call `calc_max` after that.